# MIN and MAX of dates producing wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, aggregate-functions, min

I have Payment Data and I want to show MIN and MAX dates based on different Payment Types and COUNT number of payments and adjustments.

```
CREATE TABLE Payment
(BillingId int, PaymentId int, PaymentDate date, PaymentType varchar(50), PaymentBy varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Payment
VALUES
(12345, 1, '2022-02-02', 'payment', 'Insurance'),
(12345, 2, '2022-02-02', 'adjustment', 'Insurance'),
(67890, 3, '2022-01-19', 'payment', 'Insurance'),
(67890, 4, '2022-01-19', 'adjustment', 'Insurance'),
(67890, 5, '2022-01-19', 'payment', 'Insurance'),
(67890, 6, '2022-02-02', 'payment', 'Client')

SELECT * FROM Payment
```

| BillingId | PaymentId | PaymentDate | PaymentType | PaymentBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-02-02 | payment | Insurance |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-02-02 | adjustment | Insurance |
| 67890 | 3 | 2022-01-19 | payment | Insurance |
| 67890 | 4 | 2022-01-19 | adjustment | Insurance |
| 67890 | 5 | 2022-01-19 | payment | Insurance |
| 67890 | 6 | 2022-02-02 | payment | Client |

I need to GROUP data BY BillingId and show 6 dates (issue in them, specifically in MIN) and 4 total counts (they produce correct output):

1. MIN date when Insurance made payment
2. MAX date when Insurance made payment
3. MIN date when Client made payment
4. MAX date when Client made payment
5. MIN date when Adjustment was made
6. MAX date when Adjustment was made
7. COUNT of all payments (without adjustments)
8. COUNT amount of payments made by Insurance
9. COUNT amount of payments made by Client
10. COUNT amount of adjustments

P.S. If only 1 payment was made by Insurance, for example, then MIN and MAX dates should be the same.

My code:

```
SELECT p.BillingId, 

        MIN(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Insurance' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS EarliestDateInsurancePaid,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Insurance' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment'  THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS LatestDateInsurancePaid,
        MIN(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Client' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS EarliestDateClientPaid,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Client' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS LatestDateClientPaid,
        MIN(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS EarliestAdjustmentDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentDate ELSE '' END) AS LatestAdjustmentDate,

        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentType END) AS TotalAmountOfPayments,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Insurance' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentBy END) AS AmountOfInsurancePayments,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PaymentBy = 'Client' AND p.PaymentType != 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentBy END) AS AmountOfClientPayments, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentType END) AS AmountOfAdjustments
            
FROM Payment AS p
GROUP BY p.BillingId
```

Output from the above query:

| BillingId | EarliestDateInsurancePaid | LatestDateInsurancePaid | EarliestDateClientPaid | LatestDateClientPaid | EarliestAdjustmentDate | LatestAdjustmentDate | TotalAmountOfPayments | AmountOfInsurancePayments | AmountOfClientPayments | AmountOfAdjustments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-02-02 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-02-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 67890 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-01-19 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-02-02 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-01-19 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Output I need:

| BillingId | EarliestDateInsurancePaid | LatestDateInsurancePaid | EarliestDateClientPaid | LatestDateClientPaid | EarliestAdjustmentDate | LatestAdjustmentDate | TotalAmountOfPayments | AmountOfInsurancePayments | AmountOfClientPayments | AmountOfAdjustments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 67890 | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-19 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-19 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: @Hi, Dale. I would be happy to do that, but I don't know what you are talking about, sorry. Could you please share a link where I can add my data in?

Comment: Oh, got it. Will do in a minute. Thank You.

Comment: @Dale K, added.

Comment: Great - I suggest you do that every time you post an SQL question and you'll get answers much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `max(case when..else '' end...` is causing the 1900 date, because the max function does not ignore empty/zero length strings, they are converted to date. Use NULL (or no ELSE part, defaults to NULL); MAX and many other aggregate functions ignore NULL values.

Comment: That worked. Thank You.

Comment: I actually wanted to get either NULL or blank eventually. I wanted to find correct logic first and then convert 1900-01-01 to NULL or Blank.

Comment: @Yara1994 you should always put your final desired result in your question, because many times  (such as now) its easier to achieve than an intermediate result.